# Program startup lags at fresh 14.04 LTS Install

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, system-settings

When starting 'Nautilus' Filemanager or 'System Settings' (here especially the printer dialog) the startup of theses programs sometimes lag for up to 30 seconds. Then the programs start and work normally. Immediate restart of these programs (close and start) works properly.
This problem appears when not using theses programs for a while, maybe about 30 minutes. While nautilus lags for it's 30 seconds waiting time, I can start other programs (i.e. like gimp or firefox) without a delay.

Could this be an automated background search- or refresh-event? My Ubuntu is connected to ab large network (more than 1000 nodes) via IPv4 with 1000mbit/s.
Apart from this problem, the system runs fine with good performance.

My System:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, latest updates (25. Feb. 2015), amd64
- Ram: 3,6 GB
- CPU: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5800 @ 3.20GHz × 2

What I have tried so far:

- I changed the video-driver from NVIDIA 331.113 to X.Org and back
- I disabled the unconfigured IPv6 protocol from the NIC.

Any ideas about the reason or how to do further investigations?
Thank you!

Additional Information: top output while lagging:
[image]

Comment: Have you considered that it could be a memory leak somewhere? What's your output for `free -m`

Comment: `ohahn@13hahn-ubuntu:~$ free -m
             Gesamt Belegt Frei Gemeinsam Puffer Cached
Speicher:       3700       2596       1103         12        102       1336
-/+ Puffer/Cache:       1156       2543
Auslagerungsdatei:       3804          0       3804`

Comment: [free -m output](http://www.oliverhahn.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Auswahl_003.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Additionally, it helps to prefix commands by `LC_MESSAGES=C` to force English output messages.